# PHP Codeigniter, should i set array defaults or simply use if.. else statements repeatedly

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I am utilizing codeigniter.

To allow reusability of code i have a number of functions in my model which get different things.

e.g get_details, get_features, get_products

I then have a function called get_all which calls all these methods, so If i want i can get them all but otherwise i can use them individually.

So I have my data, and I pass it to my view. My view loops through each establishment and displays various data in a table row.

At present I use if.. else statements to discern if a value is empty for example.
So if an establishment has not had its features added yet I use:

```
if(!empty($features['feature1'])){//DO STUFF e.g output 'YES'}
```

Anyway, my views code is no getting rather long and complicated because essentially for each and every key of each array returned using get_all I am using an if..else statement to output a "-" if it is not set.

It works, it just seems repetitive.

The work around I thought of is to simply set a default array whereby everything is by default set to "-", then if the data does exist it is overwritten, but then I just have to write/initiate a large default array..

So my question is not a life threatening one, nor is it particularly hard.. I am simply curious as to how one achieves such functionality without ugly code.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can "adjust" the array in the controller, by setting its empty values to `-`:

```
$features = array_map(function($value) {
    return empty($value) ? '-' : $value;
}, $features);
```

Answer (score 0):

without you posting your actual code i can only provide some general advice.  To usually handle this, and consolidate your code to remove all the conditionals put the keys in an array.

```
$keys_to_check = array('feature1', 'feature2', 'etc.....');

foreach ($keys_to_check as $key) {
  if (!empty($features[$key])) {
   // do something
  }    
}
```

This refactors out all those conditional statements into somethign that is more maintainable.

also in your model code when you are providing a general function `get_all` that calls 3 subfunctions it is extremely important to make sure that unecessary queries aren't being executed.  it seems it would be good software design to not repeat yourself, and group 3 functions into 1 but if those three functions are each executing similar queries then it is horrible for performance.